# Can I edit Angular built files?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to make a simple edit in my built Angular project. I've found the line in the main.bundle.js file and changed it. However, it's not being reflected. Do I need to rebuild?

Comment: Your build files get destroyed and rebuilt every time you do a build. It is better to fix your source files so your change is reflected every build.

Comment: Do you NEED to though? Nothing I change in the main.bundle.js is being shown when I run the app.

Comment: You can change the bundle files. What is probably happening is the browser is cacheing the file. Try a hard refresh

Comment: ahh that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can edit built files. Thanks to @LLai for helping. The changes weren't being reflected because I needed to clear my browsers cache.